# Google Custom Search API for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-search-api

I'm trying to get the first 5 pages of search results with google custom search API ...

So far I've tried to achieve the result using nested function but with no luck.
I know that I'm messing with callback but, so far I've not figure out the correct way (without using promises library) to solve my problem.

Could some of you point me out in the right direction?
Thanks.

```
app.get('/assesment', function(req, res){
  console.log('route: /assesment');
  var api_key = '';
  var customsearch = google.customsearch('v1');
  var response = "";
  var number_of_pages = 5;
  var next_page = 1;
  var exit = 0

  const CX      = 'XXXXX';
  const API_KEY = 'XXXXX';
  const SEARCH  = 'Test Query';

  console.log('start');
    // console.log('QUERY PAGE: '+pages);
    doSearch(CX, SEARCH, API_KEY, next_page, function(resp){
        res.send(resp);
    });

//
// Functions
//
function doSearch(_cx, _search, _api_key, _start, callback ){
    var response = '';
        customsearch.cse.list({ cx: _cx, q: _search, auth: _api_key, start: _start }, function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                response = JSON.stringify(err);
            } else {
                // Got the response from custom search
                console.log('Result: ' + resp.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults);
                if (resp.items && resp.items.length > 0) {
                    console.log('First result of '+resp.items.length+' is ' + resp.items[0].title);
                    for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                        response += resp.items[i].title+"<br>";
                        response += resp.items[i].link +"<br><hr>";
                    }
                }
                res = {
                    response:  response,
                    next_page: resp.queries.nextPage
                }
                // res =
            }
            _start += 1;
            if (_start < 6 ) {
                doSearch(_cx, _search, _api_key, _start, _start*10+1, 

function(resp){
                        response += resp;
                    });
                }
                if (callback && typeof callback === "function") callback(response);
            });
    };

});
```

Comment: I was able to create code to bring back all the results in one call, but instead I decided to modify the client side as well.  Search results will stream back instead of just hanging up waiting for five calls on the server side.

Have the client side ask for the next page after the previous page is loaded, this is really the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party service like [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com) to scrape Google and get back structured JSON.

Example using the [Node.js library](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-nodejs) to get 4 page of results:

```
var gsr = require('GoogleSearchResults')
let serp = new gsr.GoogleSearchResults("demo")
serp.json({
 q: "Coffee",
 num: 10,
 start: 30, 
 location: "Portland"
}, (result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```